# How to set the time period for django model

Tags: django, model

I want to keep the time period in Django model.

like `60 sec`, `10 min`.

so I choose `TimeField` class for this purpose

```
 my_period = models.TimeField()
```

Is it correct practice???

Because when I try to edit this value in admin page, there shows `am` or `pm`.

I think I should just ignore it though....

---

Thanks to the comment!

I updated the code as below.

```
import datetime
class GlobalParam(models.Model):

    my_period = models.DurationField()
    #my_period = datetime.timedelta(days=20, hours=10) ＃where should I put...??

    def __str__(self):
        return my_period
```

However it shows error...

```
 File "/Users/whitebear/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/duration.py", line 44, in duration_microseconds
    return (24 * 60 * 60 * delta.days + delta.seconds) * 1000000 + delta.microseconds
```

Answer (score 1):

For your case, [DurationField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#durationfield) is better.

```
model.my_period = datetime.timedelta(days=20, hours=10)
```

Comment: Thanks its quite helping but your example doesn't use `DurationField`. In my model class  `my_period = models.DurationField()` it made the column in DB but it says, `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'days'`